# Cannot disinstall PostgreSql by Script Bash - Linux - Must Not open dialog confirmation

Tags: linux, postgresql, bash, ubuntu-18.04

My goal is to uninstall PostgreSql (installed on a Linux host- Ubuntu 18.04 LTS) using a bash script file.
I use the following command:

```
apt remove --purge -y postgresql-12 && apt autoremove -y
```

The problem is that, launching it from the terminal, at a certain point it opens a confirmation window (you have to press enter to go on).

So when I put this command in the bash script file, it gets stuck (as I assume it is waiting for confirmation).

I tried also with 'apt-get' instead of 'apt', but nothing changed.

How can I solve the problem?

Comment: Try to use `apt-get` instead of `apt`. Apt is intended for interactive usage (see `man apt`). If it doesn't help, post your question to [superuser](https://superuser.com) because it is not programming related and chances are better to get an answer there.

Comment: I tried with apt-get, but doesn't work

Comment: Reading the docs would be a good start. Do `man apt-get` and search for `-y` or `--yes`.